# Getting Forbidden error reading from S3 using spark

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have set the spark configuration that includes the S3 access key and Secret key and setting impl.

I can see the values when i do a sqlContext.getAllConfs

But i am getting a forbidden error when reading a text file into df

```
val df = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
      .option("delimiter", delimiter)
      // Infer all columns as String
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      .option("parserLIb", "univelocity")
      .option("charset", "utf-8")
      .load(s"$path/$fileName$fileExtension")
      .replaceNullValues()
      .removeSpecialChars()
```

The file is present on S3 and the path has s3a:///folder....

Answer (score 0):

It might be you're Account doesn't have permission to read the file -but it can also mean the file is encrypted with a KMS key you don't have permission to use.